# an error appears when i clean project in codelite

Tags: c++, mingw, codelite

i am doing my first steps in C++ learning 
i am using "codelite" IDE with "MinGW" , when i clean the project i find an error appears , although i can build the project and it runs successfully 
here the build log file :

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j2 SHELL=cmd.exe -e -f  Makefile clean
"----------Cleaning project:[ project1 - Debug ]----------"
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm -f -r Debug/, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [clean] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/UNI/Documents/section4/project1'
rm -f -r Debug/
project1.mk:108: recipe for target 'clean' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/UNI/Documents/section4/project1'
mingw32-make.exe: *** [clean] Error 2
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'clean' failed
====2 errors, 0 warnings====
```

Comment: `rm -f -r Debug/` do you have some type of linux tools installed for this? `rm` is not something that windows will have by default. Maybe `codelite` allows you to change the command

Comment: `rd /q /s Debug/` would be the equivalent windows command.

Comment: i am not installing any linux soft ware 
and i don't know how to edit or change this command

Answer (score 0):

The `codelite` program creates `makefile` not designed for `windows`. My solution with `codelite` was as follows:

1. install `git`. The installer has to add path git/bin into `PATH`. This is where `sh.exe` is located.
2. In `codelite` "build settings" for the desired compiler, replace `"SHELL=cmd.exe"` with `"SHELL=sh.exe"` in the Make parameter.
3. set "Makefile Generator" to "CodeLite Makefile Generator - UNIX" in the `project` settings.

Works great for console application projects, `codelite 15.0.6`, `windows 7 x64 pro`.